# mongodb connection db is undefined with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am connecting using Mongoose using the following way

```js
import { createConnection } from 'mongoose';
this.m_context = createConnection('mongodb://localhost/master')
```

But when I try to access `this.m_context.db` it is giving me undefined.

What am I doing wrong here? I checked the connection string that is working fine in the compass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is, createConnection doesn't open connection and because of that, it was giving undefined, as it gives connection DB info only if the connection is open.

```
this.m_context = await new Promise<Connection>((resolve) => {
        createConnection('mongodb://localhost/master', undefined, (error, result) => {
          resolve(result)
        });
      });
```